# how to check if generic type mapper has key according to a string value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, objectmapper

I'm trying to figure out how to use and work with generic type Mapper and a string value:
I have a function called **getItemsPerKey<K, B>(itemsMapper : Map<K,V[]>, distinctIdsList : number[])**.The K type is either **number or string**. I would like to check if the K type value, which is either  a **string** or a **number** is equal (or apply the **has(key)** extension function) to a specific string value.

This is the relevant code:

```
export class SomeService
{
    //currently K can be number or string
    getItemsPerKey<K, V>(itemsMapper : Map<K,V[]>, distinctIdsList : number[]) 
    {
        let filteredItemsMapper : Map<K, V[]> = new Map();
        for (let [key, itemsTypeV] of Object.entries(itemsMapper))  
        {
            if (distinctIdsList.includes(+key))
            {
                /*This is problematic - "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'.
  'K' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'."*/ 
                if (filteredItemsMapper.has(key))
                {
                    ....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/w11aAw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing without typos or other unrelated issues. This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: "Please ignore typos - it is 'free handed' writing" Hmm, I gave you a link to a web IDE with your code already in it; you could fix it so that it's no longer "free handed" and actually demonstrates what you're trying to demonstrate, and it would vastly improve your chances of getting an answer you like. That being said, does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WJ81VN) meet your needs?  Note that I had to first make changes to the example for it not to spit out unrelated errors; if my changes aren't the sort of changes you'd accept, you should consider making your own changes in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the IDE. tested- fixed and updated

Comment: if K is string | number don't use generic for it, just write type for it

Comment: Oh wow I see what the problem is; `K` and `string` is kind of a red herring (although it does point to the issue). Writing up an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue here is that you are using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on `itemsMapper`,  which is *not at all going to do what you want*.  You are confusing the keys/values *held by the map as data*, verses the keys/values *on the `itemsMapper` object itself*.  You should instead be using [`Map.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries).  In other words:

- **DON'T** write `Object.entries(itemsMapper)` ❌
- **DO** write `itemsMapper.entries()` ✔

---

To demonstrate, let's make a `Map<string, number>` to look at:

```
const testMap = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]);
```

It's got two entries in it.  But if we use `Object.entries()`, nothing happens:

```
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(testMap)) {
  console.log(key, val) // nothing happens
}

console.log(Object.entries(testMap).length); // 0
```

Hmm, it has *no* entries?  I thought it had two.  The problem is that `Object.entries()` is *not* iterating over the data held by the map; it's iterating over the map's *own* *enumerable* properties.  Of which there are none.  We could add some:

```
const mapWithAdditionalProp = Object.assign(
  new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]), 
  { someProperty: "hello" }
);
console.log(mapWithAdditionalProp.someProperty.toUpperCase()); // HELLO
```

Now `mapWithAdditionalProp` is a map holding those two entries, but it also has its own property named `someProperty`. Now let's do `Object.entries()`:

```
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(mapWithAdditionalProp)) {
  console.log(key, val) // "someProperty", "hello"
}
```

So that's great if we're trying to shove some other properties onto the map object itself.  But terrible if you're trying to actually get at the data in the map.

On the other hand, `Map.prototype.entries()` is exactly intended to iterate over the data held by the map:

```
for (let [key, val] of testMap.entries()) {
  console.log(key, val) // "a", 1 ; "b", 2
}
```

---

So you should use `itemsMapper.entries()` instead of `Object.entries(itemsMapper)`.  When you do:

```
class SomeService {
  //currently K can be number or string <-- then you should constrain it to be such
  getItemsPerKey<K extends string | number, V>(
    itemsMapper: Map<K, V[]>, 
    distinctIdsList: number[]
  ) {
    let filteredItemsMapper: Map<K, V[]> = new Map();
    for (let [key, itemsTypeV] of itemsMapper.entries()) {
      if (distinctIdsList.includes(+key)) {
        if (filteredItemsMapper.has(key)) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That compiles with no error.  Hooray!  And even better, it will probably do what you want at runtime.

---

Note that the `string` vs `K` issue was indirectly telling you the problem.  Objects in JavaScript only really have `string` (or `symbol`) keys.  And `Object.entries()` only gives you the `string` keys.  So `Object.entries(itemsMapper)` is going to hand you an array of pairs where the first item in each pair is a `string`.  You get `Array<[string, any]>`.

But a `Map<K, V>` can have any type whatsoever as `K`; it can use `string`s or `number`s or `Date`s as keys (although using objects as keys in a `Map` is often not what people want to do since they are compared by reference).  When you call `itemsMapper.entries()` then, you get `IterableIterator<[K, V[]]>` (it's not an array but you can iterate it like one), and the first item in each pair is a `K`, as you want.

So the fix isn't to force checking a `string` key with `has()`; it's to check the right sort of key instead.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CyBDADjAvDM8DuMqaAFANqkBEKFANDAIwC6dlARrTAEyOMCUA3AFgAUCLHCAZiABOMYgBt4sUgGt4ATzoA3FPMYwQEmAHlWAK3jAoAOnhgo0gJaJiCZOl68YAbxEwYoJAgitbyIADmxGqaMDryXgD0CTggUAAWjmDhMGnoaHYQIgC+4oEQwfChEcSmFla29k4ublBEvKF24ekCMEkwAFoAogBKxqXg0DAAtugA6o7pAIIAJssLjuC6AArSIBjYtZY2KBAQjuFgxLgERGSU1HRMLBTsdNx8dN4w5VPwO3vwaRQdQALhgFDS8HkYQoMCKAhEZQqVUiMzQ8yWq3Wm3k-zQ1h+f12+SB6msUBAAFU0CSAMIneDETz8XrJAASgwAMpyxqJJDI5IplNFtLp9IYTOYjg0HM4IMQ0Ri0is1lANmBtsTPD4-AEJsiwpERbFdIlkhRCXjAcCOBCoTDiuIpLIFEoYKoNKK9AYjC0iDKmvLtb5hP4kSFDVFPSb4qzwQ8GDAWS8OJxHXzxJmM9ngPIThAYABlEC-QuArSOYDwHWh1nAACu0mkdig8nUMAA0gEUGAYKxq2B61N+7IBdAnFkYAAeAC0M7gkN76hA9e+aRX8mWesgDhQmRgCzgID71Yg9eAaV14SUAEkEFMIFtAR2NFOu-AAB4IMDLAvjzLZAAPjgQ4jnQABqAB8xALPAD5ECSYJEG+EGkIwkF0Gs0CZFYN6-pyjjQGCg7DoCaFeCG-j+EKMASI48gIM2yx3nBEAIYCSHoChMDgWhkFYDg+CEOgTJCLW-jOoKboejEsEPgAKuo+TgeKRhyWxeSAgGcpMhRupUQeRjEFhapgLh+GETYOHyPWywuAA1NEwb6QZhlyHRDGAvAzH3hpNJabk8pOXp4muSUoX+OFBlRXC6biEAA)

Comment: Thanks ! I've used itemsMapper.entries() in the initial version, but for some reason, it gave me an error claiming that "entries is not a known function of itemsMapper" or something like that. Any way - I'll go a head and try it

Comment: My error was that I reached the function with an json Object before it was converted to Map.